# PHP switch statement acting weird

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

```
case ($dti <= 60):
    $rating .= '1a-';
    echo $bnk;
    bnk:
    {
        switch ($bnk) 
        {
            case ($bnk >= 0 && $bnk <= 2): 
                $rating .= '2a-';
                goto docnenje;
                    
            case ($bnk >= 4): 
                $rating .= '2c';
                goto end;
                                        
            default:
                $rating .= '2X-';
                goto end;
                ...
```

It goes through the wrong case (no. 2). **$bnk** has the value of **0**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `goto`?

Comment: I am trying something out. Is `goto` the cause?

Comment: What does `bnk: {...` do?

Comment: Try removing `goto`

Comment: I am trying to build a downwards tree using `goto`. I'm using `goto` to skip some branches when applicable. Is this flawed from the very start?

Comment: Don't know - but it's something you wouldn't expect to see in modern programming(some exceptions) and so the general method would be interesting to see.

Comment: @kerbh0lz It's a label for `goto` to link to ;)

Comment: @kqdiw Regardless of what's already been said about `goto` and how you should not be using it, your `case`s are wrong. You cannot have something like `case ($bnk >= 4):` unless you're `switch`ing on `true`, which is quite confusing. Just use normal conditions.

Comment: @Jeto Aaaah, sure, ok, haven't used `goto` since 1985 (and not once in PHP) ;) Thanks

Comment: @Jeto Regular if-else?

Comment: I thought I could accomplish this with cases and goto haha

Comment: You probably could, since "a common use is to use a *goto* in place of a multi-level *break*" ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)). While I prefer `break`, I think Jeto's comments about your switch/case conditions and `switch(true)` are more relevant than the `goto` usage. Can we see the rest of your logic? For example, where are the "docnenje" and "end" target points? What's the goal of the process?

Comment: Using a `$bnk` value of zero, your code equates to `switch(0)`. Since [switch/case](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) uses [loose comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), false and zero are equivalent. So, `$bnk >= 4` evaluates to false, which is equal to zero, while `$bnk >= 0 && $bnk <= 2` evaluates to true, which is not equal to zero.